# Is it possible to create a scorecard in a top level site without using Performance point service?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performance

Is it possible to create a scorecard in a top level site without using Performance point service in sharepoint2010?

Answer (score 0):

You have everything that you can create with charts and tables with excel.

if you have those datas and KPIs in excel or lists, you can create your own diagrams.

with conditional formatting and other features in excel.

or web parts that similar to KPI lists.